# Screen not navigating in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, navigator

I wrote this piece of code in react native for the navigation from one screen to another but it seems that the page is not navigating! I come back to the same splash page, even when I clearly give 'id: 2'!

```
busButtonPress = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Bus',
        id: 2
    });
}
```

The call to the function appears to be just fine!
Please help community!

Comment: post your router code

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
busButtonPress = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Bus',
        id: '2'
    });
}
```